# Replace multiple values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update my SQL table and replace multiple values in a column with updated ones. I understand how to do it for a single value as below:

```
update [table].[name]
set [columnname] = replace ([columnname], 'December 2017', '2018 December') 
where [columnname] like 'December 2017%'
```

How do I replace multiple values e.g.

```
replace ([columnname], 'Mar-2017', '2017 March')
replace ([columnname], 'Feb-2016-test1', '2016 Feb')
```

I understand you can do a nested replace statement, but how does that work with the SET function as I cant seem to get it to work.

```
set [columnname] = replace(replace([columnname], 'December 2017', '2018 December'), 'Mar-2017', '2017 March') 
where [columnname] like 'December 2017%' or like 'Test'
```

Now this is obviously incorrect, I need some help to fix this please :)

Comment: Why is your code "obviously incorrect"?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as a `varchar` in the first place? None of the date and time datatypes have formats, they are binary values; the reason you're in this position is because of the wrong data type choice. Fix the design, fix the problem. That's the *real* solution here.

Comment: Have a look at CASE: `case when [columnname] like 'December 2017%' then replace ([columnname], 'December 2017', '2018 December')
when [columnname] like 'Mar-2017' then replace ([columnname], , '2017 March') when ... end ... where columnname like ... or columnname like ...'`

Comment: @larnu: Of course, it's the wrong data type for datetime data, but it might also be a text column with additional data

Comment: @Larnu its not meant to be a datatime datatype, its just a column of texts/strings.

Comment: @dnoeth Nice, I thought about using CASE, thanks for that i'll try it out!

Comment: @dnoeth if that is the case, then they are trying to infer data from a part of a column's value and that infers a demormalised design; which is a different problem. The combination of the 2 makes things *worse*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try CASE statement like below :

```
update [table].[name]
          set [columnname] = 
(case when [columnname] like 'December 2017%'  then REPLACE([columnname], 'December 2017', '2018 December')
      when [columnname] like ... then... 
ELSE...
END)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple values to match and replace, you can go for mapping table based approach, as given below. It is psuedocode kind of approach. You can accordingly make code changes.

1. You can have a table, which is containing the mapping information.

```sql
CREATE TABLE MappingInfo(currentValue VARCHAR(10), replacementValue VARCHAR(10))
```

2. Load the values into MappingInfo Table

```sql
INSERT INTO MappingInfo
('Mar-2017', '2017 March'), ('Feb-2016-test1','2016 Feb');
```

3. Update the table by joining with MappingInfo table.

```sql
UPDATE T
SET value = M.replacementValue
FROM TableName AS T
JOIN MappingInfo AS M
ON T.value = M.currentValue
```