# Replace multiple values in a single column from a mapping table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a table `employee_start_dates`:

| employee_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 |

The IDs have moved to a new system so each employee gets a new ID. I have a `mappings` table that maps the old ID to new:

| old_id | new_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |
| 3 | 103 |

What's an `update` command to run to replace the `employee_start_dates` table IDs?

I have tried

`update employee_start_dates set employee_id = M.new_id from employee_start_dates as emp join mappings as M on emp.employee_id = M.old_id;`.

But this command replaces all `employee_id` rows with 101 - I don't see 102 and 103.

If I do an `inner join` nothing gets updated.

Can you explain what is happening in each of the cases and what the correct solution is.

Comment: do you have a primary key on employee_id?

Comment: @sshet sorry, I redid the question. The employee_id is a foreign key to the employees table. I have dropped that foreign key constraint to update the IDs.

Comment: yes! I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61935172/359353) which is what I tried. The answer you gave makes sense. Would you be able to explain what's wrong with what I tried? Because my answer should produce the same results with the `inner join` and `on` conditions?

Comment: your query fails because it involves 3 tables: the table to be updated which is crossed-joined to the inner join between the table `employee_start_dates` *again* and `mappings`. There is nothing to connect the two instances of `employee_start_dates`.